# Swashbuckle using port 80 for https when run behind reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a .net core api documented with swagger/swashbuckle.

When running the swagger ui on localhost on url https://localhost:44390/ the "Try it out" works fine.

We have the same solution in an App service in Azure with an Azure Front Door acting as reverse proxy. Front Door only accepts https traffic and only forwards https traffic. Front door domain is widget.example.com and App service is widget-test-app.azurewebsites.net. When running the swagger ui in Azure using the url https://widget.example.com/api/index.html there are two differences compared to running in localhost:

1. The swagger ui is showing a Servers -heading and a dropdown
2. The swagger ui is showing the server url as https://widget.example.com:80

I added an endpoint in the api with the following code

```
return $"Host {HttpContext.Request.Host.Host} Port {HttpContext.Request.Host.Port} Https {HttpContext.Request.IsHttps}";
```

When requesting https://widget.example.com/api/v1/test/url it returns

> Host widget-test-app.azurewebsites.net Port  Https True

This is completely ok since Front door is changing the host header. Port is empty, though.

**Summary**: Swagger ui is showing the correct domain in the Servers -dropdown but the port number is wrong. How can I get it to either omit the port number if it's 80 or 443, or add it correctly?

**Update:** The problem is in the swagger.json file which behind the reverse proxy includes a *servers* element

```
"servers": [{
  "url": "https://widget.example.com:80"
}]
```

*Startup.ConfigureServices*

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options => {
  options.Conventions.Add(new VersionByNamespaceConvention());
});

services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o => {
  o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
  o.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});

services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
    Title = "Widget backend v1", Version = "v1"
  });
  c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new OpenApiInfo {
    Title = "Widget backend v2", Version = "v2"
  });
  c.EnableAnnotations();
  c.AddEnumsWithValuesFixFilters();

  var xmlFile = $ "{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
  var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
  c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});
```

*Startup.Configure*

```
app.UseSwagger(options => {
  options.RouteTemplate = "/api/swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
  foreach(var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions) {
    options.SwaggerEndpoint($ "/api/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", "widget backend " + description.GroupName);
  }
  options.RoutePrefix = "api";
});
```

Comment: Just ran into this today as well with a reverse proxy. Mathias, were you able to find a work around?

Comment: @BrandonBoone Answer added

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix this I cleared the Servers -list. Here is my code:

```
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    options.RouteTemplate = "/api/swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
    options.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
    {
        //Clear servers -element in swagger.json because it got the wrong port when hosted behind reverse proxy
        swagger.Servers.Clear();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can confirm it works with .NET Core 3.1 and reverse proxy from openshift v4

Comment: When I tried this (on .NET Core 5.0) I didn't need the 'options.RouteTemplate' bit.

Answer (score 1):

The solution (ok, a - mine - solution :)) is to configure forward headers in Startup.

```
services.Configure<ForwardHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardHeaders = ForwardHeaders.All; // For, Proto and Host
    options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
    options.KnownProxies.Clear();
});
```

Doing this, any URL generation in the app (behind reverse proxy) *should* respect the port-forwarding value. According to documentation known networks should be specified (taken from docs):

> Only allow trusted proxies and networks to forward headers. Otherwise, [IP spoofing](https://www.iplocation.net/ip-spoofing) attacks are possible.

See [ASP.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more details.